# ASP.NET 1.1 - VB.NET HTML Markup not reading variable from Code-Behind

Tags: html, vb.net, variables, asp.net-1.1

I am trying to dynamically change the values inside my HTML markup depending on certain conditions in the code-behind.

In my code-behind in the Page_Load(), I have the following:

```
If Not myCheck = 1 Then
    mySuffix = "_gr"
    myColor = "#cccccc"
Else
    mySuffix = ""
    myColor = "#bdd1ec"
End If
```

This is used for my HTML markup to change the way the page looks on certain conditions.

```
<table>
   ...
   <tr>
      <td style="background-color: <%=myColor%>" colSpan="6"><IMG height="5" src="/images/corner-inner-blue-topLeft<%=mySuffix%>.gif" width="5"></td>
      <td style="background-color: <%=myColor%>; text-align:right"><IMG height="5" src="/images/corner-inner-blue-topRight<%=mySuffix%>.gif" width="5"></td>
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

Now my problem is this. It works on the suffix but not on the color.
When I run my site, navigate to the page, and I do an inspect element, I get this.

```
<table>
   ...
   <tr>
      <td style="background-color: <%=myColor%>" colspan="6"><img src="/images/myImg_gr.gif" height="5" width="5"></td>
      <td style="background-color: <%=myColor%>; text-align:right"><img src="/images/myImg_gr.gif" height="5" width="5"></td>
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

It's reading the `<%=mySuffix%>` variable from my code-behind but not the `<%=myColor%>`.
I tried debugging just to be sure that it does pass something to the variable and it does.

Can someone help me point out which I am doing wrong? Or is there any other better way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't ASP.NET 1.1 deprecated by now?  Also, you tagged this C#, but show VB code.

Comment: Can we assume that your definition of `myColor` is in a <script> tag?

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately the application I am trying to change is still written in the ancient .NET version. Edited. Sorry bout that confusion.

And yes, it is in a <script> tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If not using the table is an option, you might consider using a span or div element, and give it an id, instead of using a `<td>` element. Then you can reference the span control inside the code-behind to set the style properties. Like this:

ASPX:

```
<span id="spnSample" runat="server">Hello</span>
```

.VB:

```
If Not myCheck = 1 Then
        mySuffix = "_gr"
        spnSample.Style.Add("background-color", "#cccccc")
    Else
        mySuffix = ""
        spnSample.Style.Add("background-color", "#bdd1ec")
    End If
```